# What is the diference between volume marked archive and volume marked full?

Tags: backup, bacula

In Bacula, what is the difference between a volume status at full and a volume status on Archive?

I browsed the Internet, but found nowhere to find out what means all those statuses such as Recycle, Archive, Full, Append, ...  I cannot figure out what shuld be the live cycle of the data's in a Bacula pool.  All those statuses appears a bit confused.  Where can be found some graphical summing up of what all those statuses actually mean?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

full means that you cannot write anymore information to it (because it reached quota or just full). on archive means that data has been already archived (deleted from source and are available on backup storage). Append -> still writing to / or have possibility to write on.